# Why line-clamp doesn't work in button element?

Tags: css

For example, if I write this:

```css
.a {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: gray;
}
.b {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Sure it will work when the count of lines over 2. But if I replace the `div` into `button`, it won't work. All the texts will display and I can't see the ellipsis. This is why?